# Visual Basic Script - HTML Table output not as expected

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

I've got an SQL script that outputs the data I need. Now I need to show it in an HTML table on my website. I'm not sure what I messed up, but the data does NOT get displayed in a table, instead it all gets displayed in a row that word wraps around the screen.

Here is my "billing.asp" page so far (I'll be adding more once I figure this issue out):

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
dim startdate
    startdate = request.form("datestart")
    dim enddate
    enddate = request.form("dateend")
%>

<%
    dim dbconn
    set dbconn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    DBCONN.CommandTimeout = 30000
    DBCONN.ConnectionTimeout = 30000
    dbconn.open "dsn=*****;uid=*****;pwd=*****"

    'if dbconn.errors.count > 0 then
    '   response.write "connection erros<br>"
    '   for each objerr in dbconn.errors
    '       response.write objerr.source & "<br>"
    '       response.write objerr.description & "<br>"
    '   next
    'end if
    dim billingtrans
    dim sqlstr
    sqlstr = "SELECT sq.*, sq.Total - sq.[Update] as Inquiry from ( select f.cityName, t.[employee], sum (t.TransactionCount) as Total, sum (case when  ([format] in (23,25,38) or [format] between 400 and 499 or [format] between 800 and 899) then t.TransactionCount else 0 end) as [Update] FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] t INNER JOIN [log].[dbo].[city] f on t.cityNo = f.cityNo and t.employee = f.employee and t.subno = f.subno where t.transactiondate between '" + startdate + "' and '" + enddate + "' group by f.cityName,t.employee ) sq"
    set billingtrans = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
    billingtrans.open sqlstr, dbconn
%>

<table id="billing">
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Inquiry</td>
        </tr>
<%
    while not billingtrans.eof
        response.write "<tr>"
        response.write billingtrans("cityName") &  "</td>"
        response.write billingtrans("employee") &  "</td>"
        response.write billingtrans("Total") & "</td>"
        response.write billingtrans("Update") & "</td>"
        response.write billingtrans("Inquiry") & "</td>"
        billingtrans.movenext
    wend
    billingtrans.close
    dbconn.close
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every line should be like: `response.write "<td>" & billingtrans("cityName") &  "</td>"`, also before the `movenext` instruction, you need to add this line `response.write "</tr>"`

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it might be something silly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the `<tr>` and not opening the `</td>` in your `while`. Not related, but you should also be using `<th>` instead of `<td>` in the header row.

It would also be a bit more readable (and less error prone) if you didn't use `response.write`.

```
<table id="billing">
    <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Inquiry</th>
    </tr>
<% while not billingtrans.eof %>
    <tr>
        <td><% =billingtrans("cityName") %></td>
        <td><% =billingtrans("employee") %></td>
        <td><% =billingtrans("Total") %></td>
        <td><% =billingtrans("Update") %></td>
        <td><% =billingtrans("Inquiry") %></td>
    </tr>
<% 
        billingtrans.movenext
   wend
   billingtrans.close
   dbconn.close
%>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I took your advice and updated my code per your suggestion. I can't tell if there is a speed improvement or not yet, but once its under load it might be good to have.